# problems with python-mailer and google?

Tags: python, smtp, gmail, smtplib

I've just tried the following:

```
server = smtplib.SMTP(smtpname, smtpport)
server.ehlo()
server.starttls()
server.ehlo()
server.login(username, password)
server.sendmail(username, recipient, "TEST")
server.close()
```

smtpname is "smtp.gmail.com", smtpport is 587, username is a google acc + "@gmail.com", recipient is a 2nd gmail.

could anyone tell me whats wrong? the scripts runs in python, no errors, but i get nothing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [email example](http://docs.python.org/library/email-examples.html)

Your use of "TEST" string should be a properly formatted MIME message.

In your case, it should be be:
    from email.mime.text import MIMEText

```
import smtplib

# Create a MIME text message and populate its values
msg = MIMEText("TEST")
msg['Subject'] = "TEST"
msg['From'] = username
msg['To'] = recipient

server = smtplib.SMTP(smtpname, smtpport)
server.ehlo()
server.starttls()
server.ehlo()
server.login(username, password)

# Send a properly formatted MIME message, rather than a raw string
server.sendmail(username, recipient, msg.as_string())
server.close()
```